# Is the `dfs.data.dir` property deprecated in Hadoop 2.x series?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs, configuration-files

Is the `dfs.data.dir` property still valid in the 2.x series? From this [hdfs-site.xml documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs-default.html) for what is *presumably* the version 1.2.1 and this [hdfs-site.xml documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) for what is again *presumably* 2.4.1, it is apparent that dfs.data.dir has been deprecated. Is my inference true? If so, what is its equivalent now? Change `hadoop.tmp.dir` in production and leave it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this link [Deprecated property](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html), Since the property is marked as deprecated, still you can utilize the functional behavior of the property. Better use the Deprecated property.